# Parse a time string containing a zone offset, and keep that same zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

**THE QUESTION:**

How do I parse a value that's coming in like this:

```
2015-06-19 07:32:40 -0500
```

Such that using `strftime('%Z')` will give me the US abbreviation for the timezone?  Something like this:

```
Time.parse("2015-06-19 07:32:40 -0500").strftime("%Y %Z")
>> 2015 CDT
```

The above does NOT happen right now.

I'm beginning to think it can't be done, because `-0500` has different abbreviations in different parts of the world.

**SOME DETAILS:**

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2. I cannot for the life of me get a string in this format: `2015-06-19 07:32:40 -0500` to be parsed correctly by any manner of `Time` or `DateTime` object in ruby, while returning the timezone when requested.

What I need to be able to do is parse the string as a `DateTime` (or similar) and then later output that datetime as a string including the timezone's abbreviation.  Here are some of my attempts:

This is the value that needs to be parsed into a timezone, it is received by the function as a string (as shown by the result here), which cannot be changed.

```
?> time_string = obj.created_at.to_s
=> "2015-06-19 07:32:40 -0500"
```

-0500 is CDT. `Time.parse` has the right offset in it's result... but for some reason `strftime` doesn't display any timezone information at all...

```
>> Time.parse(time_string)
=> 2015-06-19 07:32:40 -0500
>> Time.parse(time_string).strftime("%Y %Z")
=> "2015 "
```

DateTime also has the correct offset, but %Z, which should be the timezone abbreviation, returns the offset verbatim... ugh.

```
>> DateTime.parse(time_string)
=> Fri, 19 Jun 2015 07:32:40 -0500
>> DateTime.parse(time_string).strftime("%Y %Z")
=> "2015 -05:00"
```

Chronic is a time parsing library for ruby which helps with some of the headaches of parsing different formats of strings... however, it takes the string and converts whatever timezone it had into the system timezone. `strftime` is working correctly, but chronic has already changed the timezone of the result to something undesirable.

```
>> Chronic.parse(time_string)
=> Fri, 19 Jun 2015 06:32:40 MDT -06:00
>> Chronic.parse(time_string).strftime("%Y %Z")
=> "2015 MDT"
```

Please note that I can't just change the timezone setting because every time this parses a time string it might have a different offset in it, and I want *that* offset to be used as the printed timezone.

Is there a way to parse the string so that the offset is preserved, and also shown when using `strftime('%Z')`? A `Chronic` solution would be ideal, but I'll take anything at this point.

Edit:

A couple more strange finds. `Time.parse` *only* works if the offset is in the current system timezone:

```
>> Time.parse("2015-06-19 06:32:40 -0600")
=> 2015-06-19 06:32:40 -0600
>> Time.parse("2015-06-19 05:32:40 -0700")
=> 2015-06-19 05:32:40 -0700
?> Time.parse("2015-06-19 06:32:40 -0600").strftime("%Y %Z")
=> "2015 MDT"
>> Time.parse("2015-06-19 05:32:40 -0700").strftime("%Y %Z")
=> "2015 "
```

Comment: Please condense your question to the minimal details necessary to answer it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I've typed out my question as concise as I could at the top, the rest of this question is to show my due diligence.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand completely, but perhaps strptime would be better as the input is in a known format?  On my system...

```
> Time.now.strftime('%Y %Z %z')
=> "2015 PDT -0700"
> DateTime.strptime("2015-06-19 05:32:40 -0600", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z").strftime('%Y %Z %z')
=> "2015 -06:00 -0600"
> DateTime.strptime("2015-06-19 05:32:40 -0700", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z").strftime('%Y %Z %z')
=> "2015 -07:00 -0700"
```